# Reopen my question on physics

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I'm sorry for being asking non clarified questions. That won't be repeated. Is it ok to remove the ban?

Comment: The title *seems* to be inaccurate. Do you mean *"Reopen my ability to ask questions on Physics"* (or *"Reenable my ability to ask questions on Physics"*)? (Or similar.) You can [edit](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/13733/edit) (change) your question (it would be better than here in comments).